# dart callMatcher named arguments

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am following https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mocking-with-dart/ but it says nothing about matching calls to function with named argument. I have found some post from 2012 or early 2013 where it says it was not supported. can someone say something about this?

my case is simple - I try to mock and return some data if get method was called with right arguments

```dart
class Client {    
    Future<Map> get(String endpoint, {Map query: const {}, ContentType contentType:null}) {
        ...
    }
}
```

later in test I create a mock

```dart
class _ClientMock extends Mock implements Client {}

client = new _ClientMock();

var endpoint = "http://host:8080/hotels";
var query = {"param": "value"};

client.when(callsTo("get", endpoint, query)).thenReturn(new Future.value(serverData));
```

unfortunately this doesn't work, it just do not accept 3rd argument. I tried various matchers but without luck.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `callsTo` method doesn't handle named arguments, nor does the `CallMatcher.matches` method give a way to match against named arguments.

I'm afraid it seems like the mock library will need a rewrite to handle named parameters as well as positional ones.

Comment: do you know any plans to do so? Anyway I wish it was modeled after mockito  :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the unittest framework plans, sorry.